# Mobaxterm setting into mtputty

Tags: putty, mobaxterm

Do anyone knows, how we can apply any setting from MobaXterm, like font etc into MTPutty.

Any help and suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? If this is supported, it is likely documented in the official mtputty docs. Have you looked through those?

Comment: Yes I was trying that but I was not able to find any direct document to do this.. I was hoping might be someone also have tried something like this before.. that i why i posted this question.